# android opencv tracking object when triggered

Tags: android, opencv, object, tracking

I am currently working on a project involving a Android smartphone camera tracking. I am using Android Studio and OpenCV. Here is what I want to do. When I touch the screen of the camera to select an object, the tracking of the object starts (by drawing a rectangle around it).

I have already managed to draw contours and rectangles around all the objects of the frame by this function :

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mRgba, mHSV, new Size(9,9),2,2);
    Imgproc.Canny(mRgba, mHSV, 80, 100);
    Imgproc.findContours(mHSV, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0,0));
    hierarchy.release();

    for(int contourIdx=0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++){
        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(contourIdx).toArray());
        double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true)*0.02; // calcul le perimetre d'un contour
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve,approxDistance,true);
        MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height),new Scalar(255,0,0,255),3);

        Log.d(TAG, "Coordonnees (" + rect.x + ";" + rect.y + ")");


    }
    return mRgba;
}
```

But the tracking starts when I launch the app. I would like to decide when the tracking starts. And then specify the object to track.